# QSettings - how to clear the error?

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

After I call sync(), I get AccessError when I checked the status. Then I fixed the permission through program and call sync() again. This synced the settings but the error is not cleared. Is there any way I can forcefully clear it before calling second sync()? Should I subclass QSettingsPrivate and call setStatus to achieve this? If someone has achieved it, please share your code.

-Karthik

Comment: I would consider recreating the QSettings object (if you have them locally on the stack anyway) and redo your changes. Subclassing QSettingsPrivate? That's not public API.

Answer (score 0):

From QSettings docu: "Returns a status code indicating the first error that was met by QSettings". Calling sync again will not change the status. Just restart the application.